# Can't fill text on a form inside a modal (materializecss)

Tags: jquery, html, materialize

I've been trying to populate form elements inside a modal when it opens but I can't seem to do it. Been searching for hours and I can;t seem to find a proper answer.

Modal:

```
<div id="editModal" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
    <div class="modal-content row">
        <div class="center-align">
            <h4>Update Task</h4>
            <p><b>NOTE:</b> You can only update Task Name and Task Type</p>
        </div>
        <form class="col s10 offset-s1" id="form" method="post">
            <div class="input-field col s10 offset-s1">
                <input id="edtTaskName" type="text" class="validate" required>
                <label for="edtTaskNamelbl">Task Name</label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried accessing it directly:

```
$('#taskTable').on('click', '#editbtn', function() {
    $('#editModal').modal('open');
    $('#edtTaskName').text('asd');
    $("#edtTaskNamelbl").addClass('active');
});
```

I also tried accessing it as a child to the modal itself:

```
$('#taskTable').on('click', '#editbtn', function() {
    $('#editModal').modal('open');
    $('#editModal').find("#edtTaskName").text('asd');
    $('#editModal').find("#edtTaskNamelbl").addClass('active');
});
```

None of this has seems to work. Thank you for anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 6):

Not like this `$('#edtTaskName').text('asd');` try this `$('#edtTaskName').val('asd');`

for text inputs you have to use .val() not .text()

Comment: Thank you very much! This has solved my problem. I feel stupid not able to spot a mistake like that.

Comment: always check carefully, sometimes small mistake takes a day :)

Comment: Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You must have a element for click event. Its id value must be "taskTable". So

```
<input type="button" id"taskTable" value="edit"/>
```

Then, you can use it . so your javascript codes.

```
$('#taskTable').on('click', '#editbtn', function() {
```

...... your code .......
});